# Neovim flatpak version 0.5.0 don't work

Tags: flatpak

I had been starting to use elementary OS 6 lately (switched from Pop OS),
I installed the flatpak of Neovim version 0.5.0 from flathub like I did successfully with other few apps and it doesn't work, I didn't succeed to find any tutorial or explain to that topic.

- I checked in the terminal with the command:

```
flatpak list
```

and saw that Neovim is appeared
[image]

- I also checked at ~/.var/app/io.neovim.nvim:

```
ls -lah ~/.var/app/io.neovim.nvim
```

[image]

```
tree ~/.var/app/io.neovim.nvim
```

[image]

Please, someone know what's the problem and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

If the Neovim application is not starting, then there is likely a missing dependency that needs to be installed on your computer.

Here is how you can find out the problem:

0. Open Terminal (if it's not already open)
1. Check your `syslog` file for errors:

   ```
   sudo vi /var/log/syslog
   ```

   <sup>**Note:** Feel free to use a different editor. The use of `vi` here is more muscle memory than an explicit recommendation.</sup>

   You can quickly scroll to the end of the file by pressing <kbd>:</kbd> followed by <kbd>$</kbd>.
2. Look for a message that reads:

   ```
   io.elementary.wingpanel.desktop[<pid>]: sh: 1: exec: xterm: not found
   ```

   [image: Terminal — Syslog]
3. Add the missing package via `apt`:

   ```
   sudo apt update
   sudo apt install xterm
   ```
4. Launch Neovim as usual:
   [image: Launch Neovim]

---

<sup>**Note:** If this solves your problem, feel free to click the checkmark beside the answer. This makes it easier for others who have the same problem to solve their issue. You can also press the up arrow beside an answer to mark something as useful.</sup>